# Laravel API This action is unauthorized API Error

Tags: php, laravel, controller, request, postman

I am writing a couple of API endpoints and I am having an issue with the following route.

**Route:**

```
Route::put('clients/{id}', 'ClientController@updateSettingsClient');
```

it throws an `This action is unauthorized.` error whenever I run the request. `ClientController` has the required function.

It works whenever I use the build in names, 
`Route::resource( 'clients', 'ClientController',['only' => ['index', 'store', 'show', 'update', 'destroy']] );` but I will have more than one update function so I can't name them both `update`.

Any idea why it might be happening?

Comment: You need to be using the `api` guard and middleware, for example, `auth('api')->user()` and `['middleware' => ['api', 'auth:api']]`

Comment: 1. which version of laravel are you using? 2. When it works (i.e. adding resource) do you delete the line `Route::put('clients/{id}', 'ClientController@updateSettingsClient');` or do you keep it? 3. could you provide the impl. of `mapWebRoutes()` or `mapApiRoutes()` from *RouteServiceProvider.php*  depending on your configuration.

Comment: May I see your postman request?